# not able to delete data using app.delete in node js

Tags: node.js, rest, api, express

i was trying to delete the user from the `users.json` file which is in the same directory as my `app.js` from where API is called but every time i run the code, it is showing the error: "can't get/delete" ,in the browser.
i looked for the solution but didn't find any. Any help will be appreciated.

here is the `users.json` file.
`{
   "user1" : {
      "name" : "mahesh",
      "password" : "password1",
      "profession" : "teacher",
      "id": 1
   },
   "user2" : {
      "name" : "suresh",
      "password" : "password2",
      "profession" : "librarian",
      "id": 2
   },
   "user3" : {
      "name" : "ramesh",
      "password" : "password3",
      "profession" : "clerk",
      "id": 3
   }
}`

```
//app.js file   
var express = require ('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer = require('multer');
var fs = require("fs");
var PORT = 3000;

var id = 2;
//here is the delete api 
app.delete('/delete',(req,res) => {
fs.readFile(__dirname + "/" + "users.json", 'utf8', (err,data) => {
     data = JSON.parse( data );
   delete data["user" + 2];

   console.log( data );
   res.end( JSON.stringify(data));

});
})

var server = app.listen(PORT,function(){
console.log('server started at port ' + PORT);
});
```

other then that how could i dynamically give the `id` of the user from the `url`. i tried `req.params.id`, i am not sure i am doing it write.
    `delete data["user" + req.params.id];` 
this `id` will be provided in the url `app.delete('/delete/:id', ...`

Comment: please post your json file as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working fine when used `app.get`.

You just have to use `app.get` instead of `app.delete`

[image: output I received]

**Update**

http.delete wont work in the browser, it goes as a get request when you access the url from browser.

If you use postman it is working fine,

[image: Http.delete demo]

Check the sample code.

```
app.delete('/delete/:id', function(req, res) {
 var id = req.params.id ;
fs.readFile("./users.json", 'utf8', (err,data) => {
     data = JSON.parse( data );

delete data["user" + id];

console.log( JSON.stringify(data) );
res.status(200);

return res.send("Removed");
});
})
```

Comment: `app.get` worked!, but why `app.delete` is not working. and how could i make it dynamic(2nd part of the question above).

Comment: Thanks, it worked well.But  `var id = req.param("id");`  is depricated, so instead of using `req.param("id")` i used `req.params.id` and worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

Your code will work fine for API call from the postman. But, if you are trying from browser URL directly, It is a GET call(you can observe it in logging). To delete, you need to modify the GET call using URL path and callback. Hope I understood the question well.